# How to pass a Tkinter Entry through a function

Tags: python

is there any reasonable way to convert my `while` loop into a `for` loop? I tried to create this, but I never got far cause the `range`'s and/or `xrange`'s broke because the number was too large or they don't take a `float`. Here's my `while` loop that I want to see if there is a reasonable `for` loop conversion for(This is within a function is why it's indented):

```
    a = float(E1.get())
    b = (a + 1)
    c = sqrt(b)
    e = sqrt(a)
    f = (unichr(0x221A))
    fractional, integral = modf(c)
    while integral == integral:
        fractional1, integral1 = modf(a / (integral**2))
        print(fractional1)
        if fractional1 != 0:
            integral -= 1
            continue
        else: break
```

if a `range` or `xrange` is possible, it'd have to be `range(1,a+1)` or `xrange(1,a+1)`

This is my entire code:

```
def radical():
    # Define variables needed
    a = float(E1.get())
    b = (a + 1)
    c = sqrt(b)
    e = sqrt(a)
    f = (unichr(0x221A))
    fractional, integral = modf(c)
    while integral == integral:
        fractional1, integral1 = modf(a / (integral**2))
        print(fractional1)
        if fractional1 != 0:
            integral -= 1
            continue
        else: break
    d = (a / (integral**2))
    # make pointless floats integers
    if integral.is_integer():
        integral = int(integral)
    if d.is_integer():
        d = int(d)
    if e.is_integer():
        e = int(e)
    # set conditions for output
    if d == 1:
        global master
        master = Tkinter.Tk()
        w = Tkinter.Message(master, padx=5, pady=5,text=(integral)).grid(ipadx=5, ipady=5)
        master.title("Square Root")
        master.mainloop()
    elif integral == 1:
        master = Tkinter.Tk()
        w = Tkinter.Message(master, padx=5, pady=5,text=(f,d,"or",e)).grid(ipadx=5, ipady=5)
        master.title("Simplified Radical")
        master.mainloop()
    else:
        master = Tkinter.Tk()
        w = Tkinter.Message(master, padx=5, pady=5,text=(integral,f,d,"or",e)).grid(ipadx=5, ipady=5)
        master.title("Simplified Radical")
        master.mainloop()
```

Comment: `integral == integral`? Do you want an infinite loop?

Comment: trust me, this code works, but I want the while loop to a for loop, plus it has the break which would still work in a for loop long as fractional1==0.

Comment: Why do you want a for loop instead of a while ? What benefit do you see from that?

Comment: for loop is faster with dealing with larger numbers from my experience, I'm just not sure how to make this a for loop.

Comment: `for` loops aren't "better" than `while` loops. They are intended for use when you have a specific iterable you'd like to iterate over, instead of watching for a certain condition.

Comment: The title of the question and the body of the question seem completely unrelated.

Comment: That shouldn't have happened ._. That wasn't the original title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want infinite loop, you can use [`itertools.repeat(1)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) which will yield infinitely:

```
import itertools

....

for _ in itertools.repeat(1):  # instead of `while integral == integral`
    ...
```

You can also use [`itertools.count()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) or [`itertools.cycle([1])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle).

---

**UPDATE**

Using `range(integral, 0, -1)`, you can iterate from `integral` down to `1` (excluding 0).

```
for integral in range(integral, 0, -1):  # xrange if you're using Python 2.x
    fractional1, integral1 = modf(a / (integral**2))
    print(fractional1)
```

Comment: I only need a loop until fractional1==0. I have this code working, everything works fine, I just want to see if it's faster with a for loop for larger numbers.

Comment: That wouldn't serve the purpose of the code. If I wanted to do that I would need while fractional1 >= 0:

Comment: @Sergio, Check the **UPDATE** part. In short use `range(integral, 0, -1)` to iterate from `integral` down to `1` (excluding `0`).

Comment: Is there a way range/xrange could take a float that way I can see if this works?

Comment: @Sergio, No they don't take `float`. You can use [`numpy.arange`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) from `numpy` which takes `float`.